# apply font to label and button css3

Tags: html, css, label

Hello my question is as follows, i have import a font and when i applied the style to a h3 element it works fine, but when i apply the style to the label or button don't ake the font, if you can show me how to do it on this elements i will be very thakful.

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
@font-face {
    font-family: signika-regular-webfont;   
    src: url('fonts/signika-regular-webfont.ttf');
}
.fuente {
    font:signika-regular-webfont !important;    
    font-family: signika-regular-webfont, sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
    }
</style>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Documento sin título</title>
</head>
<h3 class="fuente" >este es un ejemplo </h3>
<br>
<label class="fuente" >este es un ejemplo </label>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your markup is wrong, as the following tags

```
<h3 class="fuente" >este es un ejemplo </h3>
<br>
<label class="fuente" >este es un ejemplo </label>
```

are not within `<body>` tag.

Regarding the use of `<label>`, please read http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/label

Then, I suggest you to use http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator to convert your font file(s). Make sure you have the rights to use those fonts. After converting, you will have four different webfont files (.ttf, .eot, .woff and .svg)

So your code will look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Documento sin título</title>
    <style>
        @font-face {
            font-family: 'signika-regular-webfont';
            src: url('signika-regular-webfont.eot');
            src: url('signika-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
                 url('signika-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
                 url('signika-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
                 url('signika-regular-webfont.svg#signika-regular-webfont') format('svg');
            font-weight: normal;
            font-style: normal;
        }

        /* sans-serif doesn't need quotes */
        .fuente {
            font-family: 'signika-regular-webfont', sans-serif;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h3 class="fuente" >este es un ejemplo </h3>
    <br>
    <label class="fuente" >este es un ejemplo </label>
</body>
</html>
```